# Oxymercuration of alkynes using alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry

Alkynes can be transformed into ketones or aldehydes, via the corresponding enol, by addition of water in the presence of $\ce{Hg^2+}$.

Similarly, one would expect alkynes to be transformed into enol ethers by using an alcohol instead of water. However I've looked through most organic chemistry textbooks, and they do not seem to make any reference to this. A search on Google also doesn't turn up much. I expected the reaction between alkynes and alcohol would be more commonly mentioned.

Is the reaction between alkyne and alcohol using $\ce{Hg^2+}$ only theoretical that doesn't actually in real life, since textbooks do not introduce this reaction?

Comment: Try searching for "alkyne alkoxymercuration", reject Google's suggestion of "alkyne oxymercuration" (if it pops up)